# Initializing quaternions from a 9dof IMU with semi-correct values

Tags: orientation, quaternions, sensor-fusion, imu

I am building and application where I need to switch an IMU on for around 5 seconds, and get a good orientation within the first 1-2 seconds. I am using the Madwick quaternion algorithm and it works relatively well. The problems is, if the sensor is rotated about 180 degrees while it being off, it takes a long time to find this new orientation.
Is there a way to initialise the quaternion values from the IMU sensor (instead of the standard 1, 0, 0, 0) to something close to the correct orientation? I am trying to do this by first calculating roll, pitch and yaw from the imu with the following:

```
pitch = 180 * atan2(accelX, sqrt(accelY*accelY + accelZ*accelZ))/PI;
roll = 180 * atan2(accelY, sqrt(accelX*accelX + accelZ*accelZ))/PI;

mag_x = magReadX*cos(pitch) + magReadY*sin(roll)*sin(pitch) + magReadZ*cos(roll)*sin(pitch)
mag_y = magReadY * cos(roll) - magReadZ * sin(roll)
yaw = 180 * atan2(-mag_y,mag_x)/M_PI;
```

and the converting these to quaternions with the following:

```
double cy = cos(yaw * 0.5);
double sy = sin(yaw * 0.5);
double cp = cos(pitch * 0.5);
double sp = sin(pitch * 0.5);
double cr = cos(roll * 0.5);
double sr = sin(roll * 0.5);

Quaternion q;
q.w = cr * cp * cy + sr * sp * sy;
q.x = sr * cp * cy - cr * sp * sy;
q.y = cr * sp * cy + sr * cp * sy;
q.z = cr * cp * sy - sr * sp * cy;
```

However the heading seems very random. Please let me know if you know of a method to initialise the quaternions with semi-correct values.

Comment: In case anyone has the same problem, I was able to fix this by looping the Madwick quaternion update function 10 times with each imu data instance (I divided the gyroscope value with 10). This found the correct orientation very quickly.